# Avoiding boxing/unboxing within function

Tags: scala, macros, boxing

For a numeric intensive code I have written a function with the following signature:

```
def update( f: (Int,Int,Double) => Double ): Unit = {...}
```

However, because `Function3` is not specialized, every application of `f` results in boxing/unboxing the 3 arguments and the result type.

I could use a special updater class:

```
trait Updater {
  def apply( i: Int, j: Int, x: Double ): Double
}
def update( f: Updater ): Unit = {...}
```

But the invocation is cumbersome (and java-ish):

```
//with function
b.update( (i,j,_) => if( i==0 || j ==0 ) 1.0 else 0.5 )

//with updater
b.update( new Updater {
  def apply( i: Int, j: Int, x: Double ) = if( i==0 || j ==0 ) 1.0 else 0.5
} )
```

Is there a way to avoid boxing/unboxing while still using the lambda syntax ? I was hoping macros will help, but I cannot figure any solution.

**EDIT:** I analyzed the function3 generated byte code with javap. An unboxed method is generated by the compiler, along the generic method (see below). Is there a way to call the unboxed one directly ?

```
public final double apply(int, int, double);
  Code:
   0:   ldc2_w  #14; //double 100.0d
   3:   iload_2
   4:   i2d
   5:   dmul
   6:   iload_1
   7:   i2d
   8:   ddiv
   9:   dreturn

public final java.lang.Object apply(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   aload_1
   2:   invokestatic    #31; //Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt:(Ljava/lang/Object;)I
   5:   aload_2
   6:   invokestatic    #31; //Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt:(Ljava/lang/Object;)I
   9:   aload_3
   10:  invokestatic    #35; //Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToDouble:(Ljava/lang/Object;)D
   13:  invokevirtual   #37; //Method apply:(IID)D
   16:  invokestatic    #41; //Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToDouble:(D)Ljava/lang/Double;
   19:  areturn
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you mentioned macros as a possible solution, I got the idea of writing a macro that takes an anonymous function, extracts the apply methods and inserts it into an anonymous class that extends a custom function trait called `F3`. This is the quite long implementation.

The trait `F3`

```
trait F3[@specialized A, @specialized B, @specialized C, @specialized D] {
  def apply(a:A, b:B, c:C):D
}
```

The macro

```
  implicit def function3toF3[A,B,C,D](f:Function3[A,B,C,D]):F3[A,B,C,D] = macro impl[A,B,C,D]

  def impl[A,B,C,D](c:Context)(f:c.Expr[Function3[A,B,C,D]]):c.Expr[F3[A,B,C,D]] = {
    import c.universe._
    var Function(args,body) = f.tree
    args = args.map(c.resetAllAttrs(_).asInstanceOf[ValDef])
    body = c.resetAllAttrs(body)
    val res = 
      Block(
        List(
          ClassDef(
            Modifiers(Flag.FINAL),
            newTypeName("$anon"),
            List(),
            Template(
              List(
                AppliedTypeTree(Ident(c.mirror.staticClass("mcro.F3")),
                  List(
                    Ident(c.mirror.staticClass("scala.Int")),
                    Ident(c.mirror.staticClass("scala.Int")),
                    Ident(c.mirror.staticClass("scala.Double")),
                    Ident(c.mirror.staticClass("scala.Double"))
                  )
                )
              ),
              emptyValDef,
              List(
                DefDef(
                  Modifiers(),
                  nme.CONSTRUCTOR,
                  List(),
                  List(
                    List()
                  ),
                  TypeTree(),
                  Block(
                    List(
                      Apply(
                        Select(Super(This(newTypeName("")), newTypeName("")), newTermName("<init>")),
                        List()
                      )
                    ),
                    Literal(Constant(()))
                  )
                ),
                DefDef(
                  Modifiers(Flag.OVERRIDE),
                  newTermName("apply"),
                  List(),
                  List(args),
                  TypeTree(),
                  body
                )
              )
            )
          )
        ),
        Apply(
          Select(
            New(
              Ident(newTypeName("$anon"))
            ),
            nme.CONSTRUCTOR
          ),
          List()
        )
      )




    c.Expr[F3[A,B,C,D]](res)
  }
```

Since I defined the macro as implicit, it can be used like this:

```
def foo(f:F3[Int,Int,Double,Double]) = {
  println(f.apply(1,2,3))
}

foo((a:Int,b:Int,c:Double)=>a+b+c)
```

Before foo is called, the macro is invoked because `foo` expects an instance of `F3`. As expected, the call to `foo` prints "6.0". Now let's look at the disassembly of the `foo` method, to make sure that no boxing/unboxing takes place:

```
public void foo(mcro.F3);
  Code:
   Stack=6, Locals=2, Args_size=2
   0:   getstatic       #19; //Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
   3:   aload_1
   4:   iconst_1
   5:   iconst_2
   6:   ldc2_w  #20; //double 3.0d
   9:   invokeinterface #27,  5; //InterfaceMethod mcro/F3.apply$mcIIDD$sp:(IID)D
   14:  invokestatic    #33; //Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToDouble:(D)Ljava/lang/Double;
   17:  invokevirtual   #37; //Method scala/Predef$.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   20:  return
```

The only boxing that is done here is for the call to `println`. Yay!

One last remark: In its current state, the macro only works for the special case of `Int,Int,Double,Double` but that can easily be fixed. I leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: A specialized version of Function3 generate 700+ class files for 25kb of bytecode.

Your macro is a really good start to solve this kind of problem, but think you can drop the @specialized.

Comment: you can reduce the number of classes generated by specifying for which types the trait should be specialized. If it is only `Int` and `Doublle`, you will only get 2 ^^ 4 = 16 class files. Besides, those additional class files won't hurt you in any way, as they are never loaded.

Comment: How would you drop the @specialized? Avoiding boxing is the whole point.

Comment: It was just a thought, I have to test it. Since you use the override, I think you don't need @specialized to avoid boxing, maybe I am wrong.

Comment: What about reducing the scope  of @specialized? As, for example, in... [`Function1`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/Function1.scala#L35)

Answer (score 2):

About the anonymous class which extends `Function3` (the bytecode of which you show) generated by Scalac - it is not possible to call the overloaded `apply` with primitive parameters from within the `b.update`, because that `update` method takes a `Function3`, which does not have an `apply` with primitive parameters.

From within the `Function3` bytecode, the only `apply` is:

```
public abstract java.lang.Object apply(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
```

You could instead use `Function2[Long, Double]`, which is specialized on those types, and encode 2 integers `x` and `y` in a long as `(x.toLong << 32) + y`, and decode them as `v & 0xffffffff` and `(v >> 32) & 0xffffffff`.

Comment: Nice suggestion. But i will still need to rely on boiler plate code to convert/unconvert everything by hand.

Comment: The precedence of `<<` is evil, `x.toLong << 32 + y` is in fact `x.toLong << (32 + y)`. Use more parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

As `Function1` is specialized, a possible solution is to use currying and change your update method to:

```
def update( f: Int => Int => Double => Double ): Unit = {...}
```

and change the inlined function accordingly. with your example (`update` was slightly modified to test it quickly):

```
scala> def update( f: Int => Int => Double => Double ): Double = f(1)(2)(3.0)
update: (f: Int => (Int => (Double => Double)))Double

scala> update(i => j => _ => if (i == 0 && j == 0) 1.0 else 0.5)
res1: Double = 0.5
```

**Edit:** Ase explained in the comments, it doesn't completely help since the first parameter is still boxed. I leave the answer to keep a trace about it.

Comment: How do you declare  "apply( i: Int, j: Int, x: Double ) = if( i==0 || j ==0 ) 1.0 else 0.5" ?

Comment: Intersting, but I decompiled the update method and it still boxes the first Int parameter to get the next function.

Comment: That's because the return type of the first function is not a primitive type, but an object, hence, the function is not specialized.

Comment: Interesting. So to be specialized, all the type parameters must be specializable. I didn't know it, thanks.

Comment: Another thing about @specialized, a specialized version of Function3 generate 700+ class files for 25kb of bytecode.

Comment: @jwinandy In this case I just need an (Int,Int,Double,Double) specialization and not all the combinations.