# Use Float as Int (without conversion) in Scala

Tags: java, scala, type-conversion

I'm trying to implement a fast inverse square root algorithm in Scala. The algorithm involves exploiting the binary representation of a 32-bit floating-point number by applying bitwise and integer operations to its binary representation, as though it were an Int. In other words, I must create an Int out of the binary representation of a Float, not just use a cast operator.

I remember doing something similar a while back in Java, and I believe it was done using some static method of Integer. I'm new to Scala, though, and I can't seem to find such a method. How does one do this in Scala?

Comment: you can use any java methods in scala. If you remember what that method was, please post it back here ... I am really curious.

Comment: Maybe it was `java.lang.Float.floatToIntBits(yourFloat)`

Comment: It works beautifully. I knew that Scala had Java integration, but it didn't occur to me that Scala would perform implicit type conversion into appropriate Java primitives from its own types (i.e. Float => float). And yes, that was the method I used originally.

Comment: @user74300 Since you seem to be interested in performance, note that no Scala `Float` instance is allocated at runtime. Scala's `Float` extends `AnyVal` (as opposed to `AnyRef`) which is a neat, object-oriented way to add non-reference types to the language. See also the [Tutorial](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) on value classes.

Comment: @KuluLimpa it's not allocated in general, but there is still boxing, sometimes [in a bit surprising locations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12087259/298389)